# Conditional formatting table python

Tags: python, python-pptx

Currently I have a function that puts the df elements into a table in a powerpoint slide

```
def team_kpi_slide(title, df, prs):
    df = df[['Teams', 'Leads Generated',  'Ratio']]
    team = df.Teams
    column_headers = list(df.columns)
    rows = len(df) + 1
    cols = len(df.columns)

    slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6]
    slide = prs.slides.add_slide(slide_layout)
   
    title_box = slide.shapes.add_textbox(Cm(1.5), Cm(2), Cm(5), Cm(2))
    title_df = title_box.text_frame
    title_df.text = title
    title_df.paragraphs[0].font.size = Pt(20)
    title_df.paragraphs[0].font.bold = True
    title_df.paragraphs[0].font.name = "Arial"
    title_df.paragraphs[0].font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0, 0, 160)

    left, top, width, height = Cm(5.3), Cm(4), Cm(24), Cm(6)
    shape = slide.shapes.add_table(rows, 12, left, top, width, height)
    table = shape.table

    table.columns[0].width = Cm(3.6)
    for i in range (1, 12):
        table.columns[i].width = Cm(1.8)

    table.cell(0,0).text = "Teams" 
    table.cell(0,0).fill.solid()
    table.cell(0,0).fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(0, 0, 160)

    for i in range(cols):
        cell = table.cell(0, i)
        cell.text = column_headers[i]
        cell.text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.size = Pt(8)
        cell.fill.solid()
        cell.fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(0, 0, 160)

        for k, campaign in enumerate(team):
            cell = table.cell(k+1, 0)
            cell.text = campaign
            cell.text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.size = Pt(8)
            cellWithAmounts = table.cell(k+1, i)
            amount = df[column_headers[i]][k]

            cellWithAmounts.text = str(amount)
            cellWithAmounts.text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.size = Pt(8)
```

I would like to do a conditional formatting on column Ratio in such a way min is 0 and max is 100, from red to yellow to green gradually. Is there a way in doing it without hardcoding with different conditions?